# CasperJS / PhantomJS not detecting Twitter iFrame embed

Tags: testing, iframe, twitter, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm a newbie to using CasperJS and PhantomJS and have an existing script that successfully detects DOM elements using the 'this.exists()' function, e.g.

```
var grid = this.exists('div.grid');
```

However I am attempting to detect a Twitter User Timeline feed embed (an `iframe`), but the above function doesn't appear to detect the `<iframe>` tag. I'm unsure if this is due to the fact this is an embed of Twitter's feed, but the `<iframe>` is hardcoded into the page?

I have looked at alternatives methods of detection, for example detecting the loading of Twitter's external resources, but I believe a simpler solution should be possible?

Comment: Have you checked that the iframe is actually there (e.g. screenshot or printing page markup)? Have you tried to find the iframe or have you tried to find something *in* the iframe?

Comment: Novice error. I wrongly assumed the iframe tag was embedded, but it seems this is rendered via the Twitter JS. I assume this is why it was not being detected, as it probably loaded after Phantom JS had searched the DOM.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Add `casper.waitForSelector("iframe", function(){ this.capture("screenshot.png")})`